# Iterating files with os.walk, but cannot open and print text files

Tags: python, os.walk

Currently I am trying to write a function will walk through the requested directory and print all the text of all the files.

Right now, the function works in displaying the file_names as a list so the files surely exist (and there is text in the files).

```
def PopularWordWalk (starting_dir, word_dict):
    print ("In", os.path.abspath(starting_dir))
    os.chdir(os.path.abspath(starting_dir))
    for (this_dir,dir_names,file_names) in os.walk(starting_dir):
        for file_name in file_names:
            fpath = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(starting_dir), file_name)
            fileobj = open(fpath, 'r')
            text = fileobj.read()
            print(text)
```

Here is my output with some checking of the directory contents:

```
>>> PopularWordWalk ('text_dir', word_dict)

In /Users/normanwei/Documents/Python for Programmers/Homework 4/text_dir

>>> os.listdir()
['.DS_Store', 'cats.txt', 'zen_story.txt']
```

the problem is that whenever i try to print the text, i get nothing.  eventually I want to push the text through some other functions but as of now it seems moot without any text.  Can anyone lend any experience on why no text is appearing?  (when trying to open files/read/storing&printing text manually in idle it works i.e. if I just manually inputted 'cats.txt' instead of 'file_name') - currently running python 3.

**EDIT** - The question has been answered - just have to remove the `os.chdir` line - see jojo's answer for explanation.

Comment: You might not want to read out `.DS_Store`, do you?

Comment: I just manually removed .DS_Store from the starting_dir that I am testing and still nothing =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `os.chdir(os.path.abspath(starting_dir))` you **go into starting_dir**. Then `for (this_dir,dir_names,file_names) in os.walk(starting_dir):` will loop over nothing since **starting_dir is not in starting_dir**.

Long story short, comment the line `os.chdir(os.path.abspath(starting_dir))` and you should be good.

Alternatively if you want to stick to the `os.chdir`, this should do the job:

```
def PopularWordWalk (starting_dir, word_dict):
    print ("In", os.path.abspath(starting_dir))
    os.chdir(os.path.abspath(starting_dir))
    for (this_dir,dir_names,file_names) in os.walk('.'):
        for file_name in file_names:
            fpath = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(starting_dir), file_name)
            with open(fpath, 'r') as fileobj:
                text = fileobj.read()
            print(text)
```

Comment: hey jojo,  yes i finally understand your comment on my original question.  I just removed it and it works! thank you for explaining the logic behind it!

Answer (score 4):

This line won't work

```
file = open(file_name, 'r')
```

Because it would require that these files exist in the same folder you are running the script from. You would have to provide the path to those files, as well as the file names

```
with open(os.path.join(starting_dir,file_name), 'r') as file:
    #do stuff
```

This way it will build the full path from the directory and the file name.

Comment: I tried your method but it seems to still not do anything.  Actually as a testing method, I tried using:

file = open(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(starting_dir),file_name),'r')
but yielded the same problem

Comment: What is the path for `starting_dir`? If you concatenate `starting_dir + file_name` does that create the full path to those files?

Comment: Yeah, what do the path components look like? You may also want to do a sanity check of `os.path.exists()` and/or `os.path.isfile()` on your path.

Comment: Doesn't the `os.chdir` account for the *starting* path?

Comment: tried the checking for both os.path.exists() & os.path.isfile() and both yield true....does it have to do with the .DS_Store file?  and yes the chdir does go to the exact directory so there shouldn't be TOO much of a need but I am confused and am exhausting all possibilities

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to join the root path with the file path. I'd change:

```
file = open(file_name, 'r')
```

to

```
fpath = os.path.join(this_dir, file_name)
file = open(fpath, 'r')
```

You may also want to use another word to describe it than `file` as that's a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) in Python. I'd recommend `fileobj`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to the previous answer, you will have to join the absolute path and the relative path of the walk.

Try this:

```
fpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(this_dir, file_name))
f = open(fpath, 'r')
```